# Chartjs 2.0 alpha, how to have a static scale for y-axis

Tags: linechart, chart.js

I am using Chart.js 2.0, sometimes I have series that go "out-of-scale" and so this/these series are not visible on the graph. So I decided to have fixed scales. I found on documentation:

```
// Object - if specified, allows the user to override the step generation algorithm.
//          Contains the following values
//              start: // number to start at
//              stepWidth: // size of step
//              steps: // number of steps
```

I tried:

```
{
 type: "linear", // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
 display: true,
 position: "right",
 id: "y-axis-2",
  // grid line settings
 gridLines: {
      show: true,
      ( ... ) 
 },

object:{
    start: 0,       // number to start at
    stepWidth: 50,  // size of step
    steps: 5,       // number of steps
},
// label settings
 labels: {
      show: true,
      ( ... )
 }
}
```

But y-axis-2 has not a fixed scale. Where/how should I put this 3 code lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under options > yAxes

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: lineChartData,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                override: {
                    stepWidth: 20,
                    start: 0,
                    steps: 10
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/es83ujat/

Answer (score 9):

Chart.js has removed the override functionality ([#1564](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/1564)) in v2.0 and replaced it with custom scale types and callbacks. Unfortunately, there's no documentation on this yet, but I've put together something that seems to work based on the linear scale.

```js
var UserDefinedScaleDefaults = Chart.scaleService.getScaleDefaults("linear");
var UserDefinedScale = Chart.scaleService.getScaleConstructor("linear").extend({
  buildTicks: function() {
    this.min = this.options.ticks.min;
    this.max = this.options.ticks.max;
    var stepWidth = this.options.ticks.stepWidth;

    this.ticks = [];
    for (var tickValue = this.min; tickValue <= this.max; tickValue += stepWidth) {
      this.ticks.push(tickValue);
    }

    if (this.options.position == "left" || this.options.position == "right") {
      this.ticks.reverse();
    }

    if (this.options.ticks.reverse) {
      this.ticks.reverse();
      this.start = this.max;
      this.end = this.min;
    } else {
      this.start = this.min;
      this.end = this.max;
    }

    this.zeroLineIndex = this.ticks.indexOf(0);
  }
});

Chart.scaleService.registerScaleType("user-defined", UserDefinedScale, UserDefinedScaleDefaults);
```

Then you can use a "user-defined" type and specify the ticks in the options:

```js
var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: { datasets: [{data: data}] },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: "linear",
        position: "bottom"
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        type: "user-defined",
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: 10,
          stepWidth: 2
        }
      }]
    }
  }
};
```

The key function to override here is `buildTicks` which specifies `this.min`, `this.max`, `this.start`, `this.end`, `this.zeroLineIndex`, and the array of actual tick values `this.ticks`.

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/jeffaudio/pen/xweNZP)

Comment: Is this still valid for Chart.js v2.6? Trying to get it to work for me with no success..